# Slack OAuth Setup Step 1 - Testing w/ Postman - Error: Invalid client_id parameter

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, slack-api

I'm in the process of setting up oauth [following the process laid out by Slack](https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth) for my Slack app (I've used a token previously for the same app). Unfortunately I'm hitting a snag with step 1. I'm using Postman to test out the `GET` request to `https://slack.com/oauth/authorize` by passing along 3 parameters (`client_id`, `scope`, & `redirect_uri`) expecting something that gets me closer to receiving a `code` (step 2). But what I receive is an error message of `Invalid client_id parameter`. I've checked my `client_id` in Postman against what's provided by Slack multiple times but can't figure out where this issue is stemming from. What am I doing wrong?

Additionally I'm thinking of using Passport with the Passport-Slack strategy for authentication.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this does not work is that you have defined the properties in the header, but you need to provide those as GET parameters.

To fix remove them from the header and either add them to the URL (e.g. `?client_id=xxx&scope=xxx`) or click on **Params** next to the **Send** button to enter them directly.

Comment: Never used the Params feature before before today. But that did the trick. Thanks.